# Conditional open/close tag display

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates

I'm wondering how to implement a task (which is very easy in server-side templating) in angular like:

```
{{ if condition }}
    <div class="container">
{{ endif }}

    <div class="child"></div>

{{ if condition }}
    </div> <!-- closing container -->
{{ endif }}
```

I'm of course aware of ng-hide, ng-show and ng-hide... but it think I can't use these directives to implement my task... so what should I do?

ps: I can't do the following:

```
<div class="container" ng-if="condition">
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
<div class="child" ng-if="!condition"></div>
```

because I'm using the module operator (%) in order to wrap "child" nodes into "container" every X element (where X is a dynamic parameter)

the final result would be (supposing X is 4):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

... and so on (I'm in a ng-repeat)

Comment: can u provide fiddle for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Group by filter in the template :***

The key part of the solution is that we are computing a property `containerId`, which depends on the container size and on the index of the element in the array :

```
$scope.arrayItems.forEach(function(item, index) {
    item.containerId = Math.floor(index / size);
});
```

Then in the template we group the elements by the property `containerId` :

```
<div class="container" ng-repeat="containers in arrayItems | groupBy: 'containerId'">
    <div class="child" ng-repeat="item in containers">{{item.name}}</div>
</div>
```

That `groupBy` filter in the template comes from [angular-filter](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter#groupby)

**See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/micaz/035vzqwa/5/)**

---

***Group by in the controller:***

In case you don't want to add angular-filter as a dependency, you could group the elements in the controller. The following example makes use of the `groupBy` function of [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#groupBy) :

*In the controller :*

```
$scope.itemsGroupedByContainer = _.groupBy($scope.arrayItems, 'containerId');
```

*In the template :*

```
<div class="container" ng-repeat="containers in itemsGroupedByContainer">
    <div class="child" ng-repeat="item in containers">{{item.name}}</div>
</div>
```

See **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/micaz/035vzqwa/6/)**

Comment: I think this is the most elegant and effective solution! Nice library, good advice ;)

Comment: This is great!  Any way this can be done in Angular 2?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you need the ng-repeat directive. Try something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="item1 in repeat1 track by $index">

    <div ng-repeat="item2 in repeat2 track by $index"></div>

</div>
```

Docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

You don't need an if block to add a closing `</div>`

Comment: I'm already using an ng-repeat! but I'm not barely printing a list of elements, I need to group them by a certain number of items :P

Comment: So you need to create dom nodes based on a variable?

Comment: yes, I have a collection of N elements and I need to group them in a container of X items... so If I have 40 elements and X is 4 I will have 10 container nodes containg 4 elements

Comment: So the outer repeater is iterating over the amount of containers (40/x = 10). And the inner repeater will iterate over the elements. Try some ideas on this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14198017/iteration-ng-repeat-only-x-times-in-angularjs