# Repeat Image according to AngularJS value

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a value `{{catadata2.EndorsementList['0'].Rating}}`. Value may have 3 or 4 or 5.
I want to repeat image `<img src="/assets/img/rating.png" />` according to that value. if value is 3 imaged should be display 3 time, if value is 4 image should be display 4 time.

Any possible solution to repeat image using angularJS.

Comment: use ng-repeat directive

Comment: Concern all questions at stackoverflow , but not get my amswer

Comment: Just use ng-repeat like this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16824853/way-to-ng-repeat-defined-number-of-times-instead-of-repeating-over-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try some think like this:

```
   <img src="/assets/img/rating.png" ng-repeat="imagenumber in [].constructor(catadata2.EndorsementList['0'].Rating) track by $index" />
```

You just create here array with length of rating, and repeate arrays lements, with image

Answer (score 1):

`ng-repeat` doesn't support counted loops natively; you need to iterate over a collection of some sort.

You can use a technique like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14198102/3149036) or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16824944/3149036) to implement counted loops with a function that returns a collection, defined in your controller.

#### In your controller:

```
$scope.getTimes = function(n) {
  return new Array(n);
};
```

#### In your view:

```
<span ng-repeat="i in getTimes(catadata2.EndorsementList['0'].Rating) track by $index">
  <img src="/assets/img/rating.png">
</span>
```