# How to stop repeating ng-repeat on the last item displayed?

Tags: html, css, angularjs

So i have an ng-repeat which is conditioned by an ng-if.

That's the div

```
<div class="fav-prod-customised>
    <p ng-repeat="ingredient in product.options"
         ng-if="ingredient.default_quantity == 0 && 
         ingredient.entry.quantity > 0">
                              {[{ingredient.entry.full_name}]}
         <span ng-if="!$last">,</span>
    </p> . 
</div>`
```

After every ingredient i want a comma, until the last ingredient where i don't  want a comma.
'$last' property is not working because the last displayed item is not the last item from the array.

How can i solve that?

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14198017/iteration-ng-repeat-only-x-times-in-angularjs

Answer (score 1):

## Replace `ng-if` in `ng-repeat` with Custom Filter:

Create a [custom filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter#creating-custom-filters):

```
app.filter("myFilter", function() {
  return function (list) {
    return list.filter(function(item) {
       return item.default_quantity == 0 && 
              item.entry.quantity > 0;
    });
  };
})
```

Use that filter instead of using the [ng-if](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) directive:

```
   <p ng-repeat="ingredient in product.options | myFilter">
      {{ingredient.entry.full_name}} {{$last}}
         <span ng-hide="$last">,</span>
   </p> .
```

This technique is more efficient because it avoids adding watchers and child scopes for each `ng-if`. Also `$last` and the other special properties of the [ng-repeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) directive will work as expected.

## [The DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/CJYNXLi76T2xY5DARWbw?p=preview)

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.filter("myFilter", function() {
  return function (list) {
    return list.filter(function(item) {
       return item.default_quantity == 0 && 
              item.entry.quantity > 0;
    });
  };
})

.controller("ctrl", function($scope) {
  var vm=$scope;
  vm.product = { options: [
    { default_quantity: 0,
      entry: { quantity: 4, full_name: "fullname0"}
    },
    { default_quantity: 0,
      entry: { quantity: 4, full_name: "fullname1"}
    },
    { default_quantity: 1,
      entry: { quantity: 4, full_name: "fullname2"}
    },
    ]
  };
})
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    GOOD
    <p ng-repeat="ingredient in product.options | myFilter">
      {{ingredient.entry.full_name}} {{$last}}
         <span ng-hide="$last">,</span>
    </p> .
    <hr>BAD
    <p ng-repeat="ingredient in product.options"
         ng-if="ingredient.default_quantity == 0 && 
         ingredient.entry.quantity > 0">
      {{ingredient.entry.full_name}} {{$last}}
         <span ng-hide="$last">,</span>
    </p> .
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a ternary, `{{$last ? '' : ', '}}`:

```
<div class="fav-prod-customised">
    <p ng-repeat="ingredient in product.options" 
       ng-if="ingredient.default_quantity == 0 && ingredient.entry.quantity > 0">
        {[{ingredient.entry.full_name}]}
        {{$last ? '' : '<span>, </span>'}}
    </p> 
</div>
```

Comment: You didnt copy / paste the code i amended did you? There was a missing closing  `"` and `>` on the first div.

Comment: I have corrected the html errors and still not working